# Skip key in Json serialization

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have the following case class specification

```
case class A(messages: Vector[SomeClass])
```

I would like to avoid to have a serialization result like the following:

```
{ 
    "messages":[{...},{...}]
}
```

I would like to skip the JsonObject specification and serialize the contents directly. So the result would look like:

```
[
    {
        "key":"a"
    },
    {
        "key":"b"
    }
]
```

I have tried specifying an implicit converter like the following

```
object A {
    implicit val writes:[Writes] = (o: A) => JsArray(o.messages.map(Json.toJson(_)))
    // also tried this Json.arr(o.messages.map(Json.toJson(_))) which has the same result 
}
```

but this produces an array inside an array

```
[
    [
        {
            "key":"a"
        },
        {
            "key":"b"
        }
    ]
]
```

`SomeClass` is a sealed trait and its extensions are properly serialized and deserialized. My problem is with the array nesting of case class `A`. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem using `play-json 2.8.0`, but got array as you expect

Comment: There is no need of extra lib to flatten that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Writes.contramap`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/Writes.html#contramap[B](f:B=%3EA):play.api.libs.json.Writes[B]) and [`Reads.map`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads.html#map[B](f:A=%3EB):play.api.libs.json.Reads[B]), with [`Writes.seq`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/Writes$.html#seq[A](implicitwrites:play.api.libs.json.Writes[A]):play.api.libs.json.Writes[Seq[A]]) and [`Reads.seq`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/Reads$.html#seq[A](implicitreads:play.api.libs.json.Reads[A]):play.api.libs.json.Reads[Seq[A]]).

```scala
import play.api.libs.json._

case class SomeClass(foo: String)

implicit val format1: OFormat[SomeClass] = Json.format

case class A(messages: Vector[SomeClass])

// Writes
implicit def writes(implicit w: OWrites[SomeClass]): Writes[A] =
  Writes.seq[SomeClass].contramap[A](_.messages)

Json.toJson(A(Vector(SomeClass("bar"))))
// play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"foo":"bar"}]

// Reads
implicit def reads(implicit r: Reads[SomeClass]): Reads[A] =
  Reads.seq[SomeClass].map { seq => A(seq.toVector) }

Json.parse("""[{"foo":"bar"}]""").validate[A]
// play.api.libs.json.JsResult[A] = JsSuccess(A(Vector(SomeClass(bar))),)
```

Comment: Your example works if I run it as a standalone thing but it fails with the following exception when I try to integrate it with my code `play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[No Json serializer found for type scala.collection.immutable.Vector[A]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.]`

Comment: @Niko https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is my bad. Your example works. As well as `JsArray(o.messages.map(Json.toJson(_)))` the error was somewhere else. I will consider this answer though as the correct one. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: There is no need for `JsArray(o.messages.map(Json.toJson(_)))`, as `Json.toJson(o.messages)` should work

Answer (score 0):

Just extract the *Vector* with your `case class` first:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

val a: A = ???
Json.toJson(a.messages)
```

What you would need is the format for `SomeClass`:

```
object SomeClass {
  implicit val jsonFormat: Format[SomeClass] = Json.format[SomeClass]
}
```